# Breadcrumb data-vocabulary markup for current page

Tags: breadcrumbs, structured-data

I am trying to follow documentation for breadcrumbs markup https://developers.google.com/structured-data/breadcrumbs

I am not sure if I should also put current page as a child in breadcrumbs with its link pointing to the same page? Interesting that google on that page doesnt even have current page in breadcrumbs, and looking in its page code they don't even have breadcrumb markup.

```
            <ul>
            <span itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
                <li>
                    <a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $home_url; ?>">
                        <span itemprop="title">Home</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <span itemprop="child" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
                    <li>
                        <a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $home_url; ?>/pvc-stolarija"><span itemprop="title">Pvc stolarija</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></li>
                </span>
            </span>
        </ul>
```